# I have problem about fgets I think. In menu implementation

Tags: c++, c, linked-list, menu, fgets

This bulk of code is part of whole code that i should write using linked lists. in this option of adding songs I have next output >>
what is reason of it?

```
do{

       menCh = PrintMenu(playlistTitle);

       switch (menCh){
          case 'a':{ \\this section is for adding song to playlist
             printf("ADD SONG\n");
             printf("Enter song's unique ID:\n");
             fgets(id,10,stdin);
             id[strlen(id)-1] = '\0';
             printf("Enter song's name:\n");
             fgets(songname,50,stdin);
             songname[strlen(songname)-1] = '\0';
             printf("Enter artist's name:\n");
             fgets(artistname,50,stdin);
             artistname[strlen(artistname)-1] = '\0';
             printf("Enter song's length (in seconds):\n");
             scanf("%d",&songln);
             printf("\n");
             headobj = (PlaylistNode*)malloc(sizeof(PlaylistNode));
             CreatePlaylistNode(headobj,id,songname,artistname,songln,NULL);
            break;
             }
```

And the output when using a case is : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8woVA.png)

Comment: Possible problem mixing `scanf` (which leaves the newline from the `Enter` key in the input buffer) and `fgets` (which reads the left-over newline as an empty line)?

Comment: ` id[strlen(id)-1] = '\0';` are for removing newlines

Comment: Yes, in the string you read with `fgets`. But what about the `Enter` key that you pressed to end the input for `scanf`? That's added as a newline in the input buffer. For example you have `scanf("%d",&songln);`, if you give the input `123` and the `Enter` key, that will be stored as `"123\n"` in the input buffer. The `scanf` call removes `"123"` leaving an empty newline `"\n"`. When you then use `fgets` that's the first it will see.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). What does `PrintMenu` do? At a guess it's leaving a newline character in stdin which the first `fgets` immediately reads and hence appears to skip that first input.

Comment: Also note that using `strlen` like you do without checking that `fgets` was successful, or that it indeed added the newline, is dangerous. I recommend something like `buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\n")] = 0;` instead.

Comment: `char PrintMenu(char title[]){
      char menuchar;
      
      printf("%s PLAYLIST MENU\n", title);
      printf("a - Add song\n");
      printf("r - Remove song\n");
      printf("c - Change position of song\n");
      printf("s - Output songs by specific artist\n");
      printf("t - Output total time of playlist (in seconds)\n");
      printf("o - Output full playlist\n");
      printf("q - Quit\n");
      printf("\n");
      printf("Choose an option:\n");
      scanf(" %c", &menuchar);
      return menuchar;
      } `

Comment: this is printmenu function

Comment: Please [edit] your question instead of posting code as comments.

Comment: And that `scanf(" %c", &menuchar);` followed by `fgets(id,10,stdin);` is the problem.

Comment: You may try add "fflush(stdin)" to empty input buffer before fgets.

Comment: @ytlu Bad advice. Passing an input-only stream (like `stdin`) to `fflush` is explicitly mentioned in the C specification as *undefined behavior*. It's a non-portable and non-standard extension in some environments.

Comment: @Some programmer dude Checked. Thank you for correction.

Comment: Online suggests two ways to empty the input buffer: 1. while ( (c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF ) ; gets char one by one,  Or 2,  scanf("%*[^\n]"); whic reads all '\n' and discards. You may try one of them before the gets().